# connecting to databases The wait operation timed out

Tags: asp.net

I've gotten the problem of connecting to databases for 1 month (it's safe to guess one)

plz check error in image screen shot

[image: Sample Image]

[image: Sample Image]

[image: Sample Image]

[enter link description here](https://barnamenevisan.org/Forums/Post12152.html)

Comment: check your connection string. is it proper.

Comment: Post code please

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problem came from the ISP and its open ports. `SQL Server` uses `1433` port to establish a connection with clients as default. You can change this port on the server and resolve the problem.

**Note**: You connection string must be updated after this change.

*Hope It'll help.*